# SQL get rows in '= ALL' style

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, match

I have simple many-to-many relation in table Product_Category (MSSQL 2008 r2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Product_Category (ProductId int, CategoryId int);
go
INSERT INTO #Product_Category (ProductId, CategoryId)
VALUES (1, 200);
go
INSERT INTO #Product_Category (ProductId, CategoryId)
VALUES (2, 200);
go
INSERT INTO #Product_Category (ProductId, CategoryId)
VALUES (2, 400);
go
INSERT INTO #Product_Category (ProductId, CategoryId)
VALUES (3, 300);
go
INSERT INTO #Product_Category (ProductId, CategoryId)
VALUES (2, 300);
go
DROP TABLE #Product_Category
```

How can I select ProductId with condition: CategoryId = 200 *and* CategoryId = 300 *and* CategoryId = 400?

Query example (sql below doesn't work):

```
SELECT ProductId FROM #Product_Category
WHERE CategoryId = ALL (select 200 union select 300 union select 400)
```

**I expect result: ProductId = 2**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select PC.ProductId
from #Product_Category as PC
where PC.CategoryId in (200, 300, 400)
group by PC.ProductId
having count(distinct PC.CategoryId) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: 
It is still ugly but it does work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT master.ProductId
FROM #Product_Category master
JOIN (
    SELECT ProductId, 
           cat200 = max(case when CategoryId=200 then 1 else 0 end),
           cat300 = max(case when CategoryId=300 then 1 else 0 end),
           cat400 = max(case when CategoryId=400 then 1 else 0 end)
   FROM #Product_Category
   GROUP BY ProductId
) sub ON sub.ProductId = master.ProductId
WHERE cat200=1
  and cat300=1
  AND cat400=1
```

Comment: Query found ProductId: 1, 2, 2, 3, 2

Comment: @Alexander: Solution posted. Even uglier, but it works. I will now see how to pretty it up with more modern syntax.

Comment: I wouldn't even save that SQL statement without a bag on its head, but an ugly statement that gets the job done is better than a pretty one that doesnt. Just barely though ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT a.ProductId 
    FROM Product_Category as a, 
        Product_Category as b, 
        Product_Category as c 
        WHERE a.CategoryId = 200 
            And b.`CategoryId` = 300 
            And c.`CategoryId` = 400 
            And a.`ProductId` = b.`ProductId` 
            And b.`ProductId` = c.`ProductId`
```

for more like 500 and 600

```
SELECT a.ProductId 
    FROM Product_Category as a, 
        Product_Category as b, 
        Product_Category as c,
        Product_Category as d,
        Product_Category as e,
        WHERE a.CategoryId = 200 
            And b.`CategoryId` = 300 
            And c.`CategoryId` = 400 
            And d.`CategoryId` = 500 
            And e.`CategoryId` = 600 
            And a.`ProductId` = b.`ProductId` 
            And b.`ProductId` = c.`ProductId`
            And c.`ProductId` = d.`ProductId`
            And d.`ProductId` = e.`ProductId`
```

check live demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8965e/1/0

Comment: Coudl you post code so that it is readable, rather than scrolling off the page? I can't even copy paste it off of that into my srver.

Comment: It returns 27 rows of '2', which can be reduced by adding a DISTINCT, but seems rather wasateful to be creating that many duplicate records.

Comment: omg :) Is there a more elegant solution? I gave an example with three CategoryId, but there may be any number of CategoryId

Comment: Looks like you are using MySQL syntax...@AlexanderByndyu is using SQL Server.

Comment: @M.I.T. I think you are missing the point of Alexander's reaction. How to do this without hardcoding all the seection values?

Answer (score 1):

Here I am using a CTE, but you could use a table variable or something different for the `category_filter`.

```
with category_filter as (
    select * from (values (200), (300), (400)) as v(id)
)
select distinct ProductId
from #Product_Category
join category_filter
    on (#Product_Category.CategoryId = category_filter.id)
group by ProductId
having COUNT(distinct CategoryId) = (select COUNT(*) from category_filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also ugly solution :)

```
WITH category_filter1(CategoryId) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (200), (300), (400)) tmp1(tmp2)
)
SELECT p.ProductId
FROM (
    SELECT ProductId,
        CASE WHEN CategoryId IN (SELECT CategoryId FROM category_filter1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END f
    FROM #Product_Category
    ) p
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.f
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category_filter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Values as Table Source and check them in WHERE clause with NOT EXISTS and [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
SELECT *
FROM #Product_Category p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (                                                        
                  SELECT Match
                  FROM (VALUES(200), 
                              (300),
                              (400))
                  x(Match)
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT CategoryId
                  FROM #Product_Category p2
                  WHERE p.ProductID = p2.ProductID
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e9534/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH L AS (
SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES (200),(300),(400)) AS T(CategoryId)
)
SELECT ProductId
  FROM Product_Category P
 INNER JOIN L
    ON L.CategoryId = P.CategoryId
 GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(1) = (SELECT Count(1) FROM L)
;
```

The WITH disappears if you are planning to use TVP.