# Many conditions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I encounter a problem with a SQL query... I have 3 tables (Images, Tags, Image_Tag) :

**Images**

```
Image_ID  |  Image_Path
1            img1.png
2            img2.png
3            img3.png
```

**Tags**

```
Tag_ID    |  Name
1            Tag 1
2            Tag 2
3            Tag 3
```

**Image_Tag**

```
Image_ID  |  Tag_ID
1            2
2            3
3            1
3            2
```

As you can see the third image has two tags : Tag1 and Tag2. I would like to create a query  which selects images that have all the passed tags.

For example if I give the **Tag 2** I receive images #1 and #3, but if I add the **Tag 1** I receive only the image #3.

I tried to use the **IN** condition, but it returns me all results that match a tag.

Have you got any idea ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    Images a
        INNER JOIN Image_Tag b
            ON a.Image_ID = b.Image_ID
        INNER JOIN Tags c
            ON b.Tag_ID = c.Tag_ID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Tag2')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for Tag2*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d00b1/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*for Tag1*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d00b1/3)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Images a
        INNER JOIN Image_Tag b
            ON a.Image_ID = b.Image_ID
        INNER JOIN Tags c
            ON b.Tag_ID = c.Tag_ID
WHERE   c.Name IN ('Tag1','Tag2')
GROUP   BY a.Image_ID, a.Image_Path
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d00b1/7)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: Cool, thank you JW! However I do not know how many tags users will send me... I could limit the number of tags, but the ideal would be not to do it.

Comment: *..I do not know how many tags users will send me.* -- why don't you parameterized the query?

Comment: I do it in PHP => $query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM images INNER JOIN tag_image ON images.id_image = tag_image.id_image WHERE tag_image.id_tag IN (%s);", $tags)); <= where $tags can be 1,2 or 1,4,5 or 3...

Comment: This question deals with the same query structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171029/sql-get-rows-in-all-style/15171076#15171076

Comment: @PieterGeerkens this is not a relational division problem. It doesn't need to have `JOIN`s or `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Yes I tried, unfortunately it doesn't work when I select multiple Tags in the IN condition :s

Comment: @JW: Have you read this part of the question?  "I would like to create a query which selects images that have all the passed tags."

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the question got edited after JW's answer, even the update, because he's got a lot of rep and the answer to this problem using `HAVING` and `COUNT` is pretty standard. I'm starting from his answer. This version works for an arbitrary number of tags, of which you want all matching the image.

```
SELECT  a.Image_ID, a.Image_Path
FROM    Images a
    INNER JOIN Image_Tag b
        ON a.Image_ID = b.Image_ID
    INNER JOIN Tags c
        ON b.Tag_ID = c.Tag_ID
GROUP BY a.Image_ID, a.Image_Path
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tags)
```

I discourage you from using `Name` or any SQL other reserved word as a column name. And I assume the `Name` is unique. I should mention that not all RDBMS will allow the `SELECT` in the `HAVING`, even though it isn't correlated to the main query. For those, you can try something like

```
SELECT  a.Image_ID, a.Image_Path, c.Tag_ID
FROM    Images a
    INNER JOIN Image_Tag b
        ON a.Image_ID = b.Image_ID
    LEFT JOIN Tags c     -- Note change to an OUTER JOIN!
        ON b.Tag_ID = c.Tag_ID
GROUP BY a.Image_ID, a.Image_Path
HAVING   COUNT(*) = COUNT(c.Tag_ID)
```